# Cerdit has deducted but sms not deliverd using api in php

Tags: php, sms, sms-gateway

My problem is that i am trying to send a sms to confirm registration when user register. when  curl_exec() function run it returns **OK [8665ce55-3d34-11e7-a0d4-14187734a8d9]** and one credit has deducted from my sms panel account, but not recieved to user.

`$sms='Dear '.$_POST['name'].'`, 
You have successfully registered for 9th CENTRAL ZONE & 39th UP STATE ANNUAL CONFERENCE OF INDIAN SOCIETY OF ANAESTHESIOLOGISTS to be held at Scientific Convention Center, KGMU, Lucknow from 1st to 3rd September, 2017. Your registration id is **'.$reg_id.'**. Kindly send us the payment details to confirm your conference registration at czupisacon@gmail.com or pay online. Best Regards - Conference Secretary';

```
$vars="username=".$user."&password=".$pass."&senderid=".$sid."&to=".$mobile."&text=".$msg."&route=".$route."&type=text";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $vars);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
echo $result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: I think it may be a problem from your service provider, did you try contacting them ?

Comment: If you are using a third party API ask their support team to give you an example in your programming language.. Also have them check their logs to see why the credits are being deducted and no message is received..

Comment: replacing & to and in $sms ,its working thank u Mehdi Bounya and Chirstopher smit